# I want to change reference frame when I encode P or B frame

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg

I searched example C code about YUV->.MP4 encoding. I found something, but I want to change reference frame to specific frame when I encode B or P frame.

I use `avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_packet);` function in `avcodec.h` when I encode a frame.

I think that reference frames exist in `AVCodeccontext`, `AVFrame` or `AVPacket` because when the frame is encoded, encoder needs a reference frame. But I can't found.

In other words, I want to encode P or B frame using a specific frame, not using an automatically chosen frame. If anyone knows how to do this, please tell me.

Comment: Question rephrased+reformatted as much as I could.

Comment: @nop77svk thanks!! :)